# Relation of divisibility - hasse diagram

Tags: divisibility, relations

$A = \{3,4,5,10,15,20,30,60\}$

Relation $R: \forall x,y \in A : (x,y) \in R \Leftrightarrow y \mid x $

[Here is my Hasse diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlHe2.png)

Is my Hasse diagram drawn correctly?

Comment: Yes $\ \ \ \  \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct.

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/554342)

Comment: @H.R. I disagree.  The question was stated "Is my Hasse diagram drawn correctly?"  The answer to which is simply yes.  No additional information is needed since the OP clearly already knows what he is doing.  If anything it is the question that should be closed, not the answer to be removed.  My only purpose of posting this answer was to remove the question from the unanswered queue.  Points from doing so are unnecessary, hence why I put it as a wiki answer instead.

Comment: OK! But this could be a comment. :)

Comment: @H.R. in which case, the question would remain open and unanswered forever.  I think *that* is more detrimental.

Comment: Maybe you are right! :) It is matter of taste. Yes or No answers are too short in my sense. :)